# Inner Exception error when showing a form

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms

For the past hour, whenever I attempt to open a form, an error has been popping up;

An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

For simple code like;

```
formbooking.show()
```

Whenever I reference this form in anyway, that error pops up. I haven't done anything related to that form recently and I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when that happens to me, I have an Array that is being indexed using some outside value and the data that is being passed is greater than what the Array was dimensioned for. You will need to set a breakpoint on your New Subroutine and step through your program to determine where your problem is.

Comment: I see. I didn't make a new Subroutine if that was what you were saying but I just began commenting chunks of my program out until I narrowed it down to the problematic one.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When you try to show the form, it needs to be constructed. That means in the `sub new()` method, you have some wrong code that refers to a non-existing array index.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying sorry.